# Im facing this error Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages when trying to run composer update

Tags: php, composer-php

the error is as follows:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\attachment_perfomance_munashe-main\attachment_perfomance_munashe-main>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.48.4] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.26.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.15.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.26.0] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.25.1].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.15.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.25.1] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.48.4].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

I enabled the fileInfo extensions in the config file

Comment: How did you ensure that `ext-fileinfo` is really enabled?

Comment: `I enabled the fileInfo extensions`... Composer seems to disagree with you, and it can't lie! Remember that command-line PHP and Web PHP have different config files. Make sure you enabled it in both